# return content between `And ` keyword using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-group

I need to split a string by the `and` operands (and eventually `Or`) but I'm not sure how to go about it.

For example, if I have the following string

```
Name contains 'al' and Country equals 'US|UK|FR' and Status equals 'Open|Closed'
```

I would like to get back an array containing the following:

```
[0]Name contains 'al' 
[1]Country equals 'US|UK|FR'
[2]Status equals 'Open|Closed'
```

If I only have `Name contains 'al'` without any `and`, it should just return the provide string

```
[0]Name contains 'al'
```

I've tried simple things like:

1. `(and)` but this only returns the and rather than the content.
2. `(?<=and)(.*)(?=and)` but this returns the content of the second and does not include the first or last.
3. `\b(and )` but again this only returns the and I don't understand why if I include a space in front of `and` if won't find any instances.
4. `.*(\b(and))` but this skips the first `and` and returns the content all the way to the second `and`

Can you help?

Thanks

NOTE: This will be used in a .net 2019 project.

Comment: Maybe `s.Split(new[] {"and", "or"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` will do? Well, you may try `Regex.Split(s, @"(?i)\s*\b(?:and|or)\b\s*")`, too

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can't believe I didn't think of this sooner! I was just stuck with the idea of using RegEx for this when I should have thought about what was already and easily available! The Split did the trick alright! Thanks. Might want to stick that as an answer btw.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh and btw, your RegEx works a charm as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to just split on `and` or `or` substrings use `String.Split`:

```
var results = s.Split(new[] {"and", "or"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If you need to split with `or` or `and` as whole words you need a `Regex.Split`:

```
var results = Regex.Split(s, @"\s*\b(?:and|or)\b\s*");
```

Here,

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\b` - makes sure the word starts here
- `(?:and|or)` - a non-capturing group matching either `and` or `or` substrings
- `\b` - the end of a word
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

If you need case sensitivity use `(?i)` inline modifier or `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`:

```
var results = Regex.Split(s, @"(?i)\s*\b(?:and|or)\b\s*");
var results = Regex.Split(s, @"\s*\b(?:and|or)\b\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```